# Certificates needed for Https connection to REST oauth2 client

Tags: ssl-certificate, spring-oauth2, oauth2client

I have a spring-boot application, I want to access a REST API (oauth2) to get user information. I need to add certificates for this to my application as the connection is https. I was provided with two files

```
    XXX_Root_CA_3_DER.crt and 
    XXX_Root_CA_3_PEM.cer. 
XXX_Sub_CA_3_DER.crt and 
    XXX_Sub_CA_3_PEM.cer
```

I need to use these certificates with spring Webclient to get the connection. I coded the webclient part, now I need to make this certificate conversion and place them in the application somewhere.

I converted these certificates in gitbash as

```
 winpty openssl pkcs12 -in XXX_Root_CA_3_DER.crt -out XXX_Root_CA_3.p12
```

Now I have just one file XXX_Root_CA_3.p12 but I dont how to use it because I am referring to this (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate) where I need to have some password to store in the trustore in my client application.

**Could someone please suggest some steps that I need to follow for conversion of certificate files, which files I need to use and how to use these files with WebClient**. There is lot of information on the internet I am confused how to implement this.

Comment: The link you sent is about how to set-up a spring-boot server with HTTS self sighned. But you are asking about how to conect with a client.
Your webclient probably supports https, and you don't need to play with certificates on the client side (unless client side certificates are required by the server).
The issue might be that you want rest client with outh2, which have diffrent solutions.
I think I need some more info in order to be able to answer

Comment: Hi, the link which I sent have a section for client underneath . I need to connect my client application to the remote REST api which uses oauth2 (password grant type). I was informed the API team to use the above mentioned certificates. I have to use WebClient (not RestTemplate) to make https call. Please let me know what information  you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a client, you just need to ensure that your Java runtime trusts the server. You seem to have been given two certificate authorities:

- A root CA
- An intermediate CA

You should just need to run commands like this:

```bash
sudo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool" -import -alias xxxroot -cacerts -file ./XXX_Root_CA_3_DER.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt

sudo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool" -import -alias xxxintermediate -cacerts -file ./XXX_Sub_CA_3_DER.crt -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

My [development SSL](https://authguidance.com/developer-ssl-setup/) blog post provides further info. See also my [example certs](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.developmentcertificates/tree/master/mycompany) and ensure that your CA certs have a similar format to the one called `mycompany.ca.pem`.